# Div onload function and embedding server code c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to call c# properties in .aspx page, where myfunc is jquery function.
this function take parameters which i am passing through c# public properties. and I want to call this function as soon as div  is rendered.previously i have done this  on prerender event  in ascx control.  wha is exact ssyntax for below code and  calling jquery function from here is valid?

```
    <div  class ="v" onload ="Javascript:myfunc('<%= this.articleID  %> '      
     ,'" +<%=this.UserID %>+"','" +<%=this.EncryptedUserID %>" +','" +<%# 
     this.ItemIndex  %>)">
```

thanks

Edited

Ok If i do like this way

```
            <div  class ="v"  >
                         <script language ="javascript" >

                          JGetTotalVotes(<%= this.articleid  %>  ,<% 
              this.ThisEncryptedUserID %>,<% this.ItemIndex  %>,'aaa');
                          </script>
```

I  do not want server side hidden fields solutions and if i use hiden field ( non server html tag) then i still need to call <%%> to fetch value from server side to hiddent field

Answer (score 1):

I see you are missing single quote after the last parameter if that is not the problem. 
You can use hidden fields and call the function in javascript

Add this to your page

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnArticleId" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnUserId" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnEncryptedUserID" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnItemIndex" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

bind those hiddenfields in Page_Load event remember to add ClientIDMode="Static" to set the id as you set not a generated one by asp.net to have the ability to use them in javascript

Add To your javascritp

```
function YourFunction(){
     var ArticleId = document.getElementById("hdnArticleId").value;
     var UserId= document.getElementById("hdnUserId").value;
     var EncryptedUserID= document.getElementById("hdnEncryptedUserID").value;
     var ItemIndex= document.getElementById("hdnItemIndex").value;
     // your code goes here
}
```

and don't forget to call your javascript function in page onload

Comment: I dont want to use any server side controls as i want to avoid viewstate problems.prevously i have used server side controls but i am moving to pure stateless desgin.

Comment: I hate to mix server code with JavaScript, so I would use this approach of loading the necessary data into hiddenfields.

Comment: @klusner - You can turn off ViewState and still use server controls. They just won't repopulate automatically on a postback.

Comment: the problem here is passing values to javascript your getting the values using a server side code so to pass it to javascript you have to do that 

I have another solution to do all the work using Ajax call. by creating an ajax call returning the values you want "ArticleId,UserId etc .." the use of these values in javascript will  be easy now

Comment: Hello @Zara_me, if it helped you can you please also vote up and mark as answer, unless you need any further help?

Answer (score 0):

Div elements don't pull in external content, so they don't have load events.

If you want to run some JS after a div element has been parsed:

```
<div></div>
<script> foo(); </script>
```

Comment: how will i pass values to foo(arg1,arg2,arg3) from                       <div><script>foo(<% this.arg1%>,<% this.arg1%>,<% this.arg1%>)</script></div>

Comment: err… like that: `foo(arg1,arg2,arg3)`